# Bootstrap Carousel Item background image is not showing in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a wordpress site using bootstrap. I have a carousel which is set to 100vh. This displays correctly in all browsers apart from safari. below is the code.

Below is the relvant css code:

```js
(function( $ ) {

 //Function to animate slider captions 
 function doAnimations( elems ) {
  //Cache the animationend event in a variable
  var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
  
  elems.each(function () {
   var $this = $(this),
    $animationType = $this.data('animation');
   $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
    $this.removeClass($animationType);
   });
  });
 }
 
 //Variables on page load 
 var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
  $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
  
 //Initialize carousel 
 $myCarousel.carousel();
 
 //Animate captions in first slide on page load 
 doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);
 
 //Pause carousel  
 <!--$myCarousel.carousel('pause');-->

 
 //Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
 $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
  doAnimations($animatingElems);
 });  
 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
 -webkit-height:1000px;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: cover;

}

#mycarousel {
 max-height: 100vh;
}
.carousel,
.item,
.active {
 padding-top:0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:2;
}
.carousel h1 {
 font-size: 50px;
}
.carousel h2 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 2%;
 text-shadow: none;
 font-weight: 500; 
}
.carousel h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 2%;
    margin-top: 10px;
 text-shadow: none;
 font-weight: 300; 
}
.carousel-inner {
    /*height: 100%;*/
   height:calc(100vh - 115px); 
 margin:0 auto;
}
.carousel-caption {
 position: absolute;
   right: 37%;
   bottom: 20px;
   left: 37%;
  bottom: 40%;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 max-width: 26%;
 min-height: 5%;
  color: #caaa77;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
 padding: 5px 20px;
 text-align:center;
/* border: 5px solid #caaa77;*/
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
     -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
       -o-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
}
.carousel-caption p {
    color: #1d2532;
    padding: 2% 20%;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-style: italic;
}
.carousel-caption p a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #1d2532; 
}
.carousel-indicators {
 bottom: 30%;
}
.carousel.fade {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel.fade .item {
  transition: opacity ease-out linear 1.7s;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0; /* hide all slides */
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.carousel.fade .item:first-child {
  top: auto;
  /*opacity: 1; /* show first slide */
  position: relative;
}
.carousel.fade .item.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel.icon-prev {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -95px;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}
.carousel.icon-next {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 67px;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}
.side-controls-block {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 30px;
    /*top: 10px;*/
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
.side-controls-block div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
}

.side-controls-block a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.side-controls-block a:hover {
 color:#1d2532; 
}
 
.side-controls-block.chev-left a:hover {
  border: 0.1em solid #1d2532;
}

.side-controls-block a:hover.chev-left:after, a:hover .right:after a:hover:down {
  border-top: 0.1em solid #caaa77;
  border-right: 0.1em solid #caaa77;
}

.side-controls-block.chev-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 0.1em solid #caaa77;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
.side-controls-block.chev-left:after {
  content: '';
 display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0.7em;
  margin-left: 0.6em;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border-top: 0.1em solid #caaa77;
  border-right: 0.1em solid #caaa77;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.side-controls-block.chev-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 0.1em solid #caaa77;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.side-controls-block.chev-right:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0.7em;
  margin-left: -0.6em;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border-top: 0.1em solid #caaa77;
  border-right: 0.1em solid #caaa77;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.down-controls-block {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    /*top: 10px;*/
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
.down-controls.chev-down {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.down-controls.chev-down:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0.7em;
  margin-left: -0.6em;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border-top: 0.1em solid #caaa77;
  border-right: 0.1em solid #caaa77;
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    /*top: 10px;*/
    display: block;
 z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.carousel-image {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

 Here is the carousel code from the page itself:
```

```html
    <header id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel" data-interval="10000" data-pause="false">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>            
        </ol>

        

        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class=" item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->             
            <div class=" fill animated kenburns-top carousel-image" style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('carousel_grid_image_1');?>')"></div>
                <div data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one" class="carousel-caption">
                    <img>  
                    <h3 data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one">
                      <?php the_field('carousel_title_1'); ?>
                    </h3>
                    <p data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one">
                    <a href="<?php the_field('carousel_link_1'); ?>"><?php the_field('carousel_subtitle_1'); ?></a> 
                    </p>              
                </div>
            </div>
   <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill animated kenburns-top" style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('carousel_grid_image_2'); ?>');"></div>
                <div data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one" class="carousel-caption">
                    <img>  
                    <h3 data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one">
                      <?php the_field('carousel_title_2'); ?>
                    </h3>
                    <p data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one">
                        <a href="<?php the_field('carousel_link_2'); ?>"><?php the_field('carousel_subtitle_2'); ?></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
   <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill animated kenburns-top" style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('carousel_grid_image_3'); ?>');"></div>
                <div data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one" class="carousel-caption">
    <img>  
                    <h3 data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one">
                      <?php the_field('carousel_title_3'); ?>
                    </h3>
                    <p data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one">
                      <a href="<?php the_field('carousel_link_3'); ?>"><?php the_field('carousel_subtitle_3'); ?></a>
                    </p>              
                </div>
            </div>
   <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill animated kenburns-top" style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('carousel_grid_image_4'); ?>');"></div>
                <div data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one" class="carousel-caption">
    <img>
                    <h3 data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one">
                      <?php the_field('carousel_title_4'); ?>
                    </h3>
                    <p data-animation="animated fade-in-auto one">
                    <a href="<?php the_field('carousel_link_1'); ?>"><?php the_field('carousel_subtitle_4'); ?></a> 
                    </p>           
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.item -->
            
    
          </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
    
        </div><!-- /.carousel -->
        <!-- Controls -->
        <div class="side-controls-block">
          <div class="controls"> 
            <a class="left carousel-control animated fade-in-auto one" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="side-controls-block chev-left"></span>
            </a>
        
            <a class="right carousel-control animated fade-in-auto one" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                   <span class="side-controls-block chev-right"></span>
            </a>
    </div><!--/.controls -->
```

If I change the .fill css so that height:300px; instead of height:100vh; it displays.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Give .item a height for the 100vh to fill. CSS hierarchy is working against you

Comment: Thanks so much that appears to have sorted it.